# Convert String of characters to Float dynamically

Tags: c

I've been having some problems with this code below...

The main idea of the code is to read line by line and convert chars strings into floats and save the floats in a array called `nfloat`.

The input is a `.txt` containing this: *n* = the number of strings, in this case *n* = 3

```
3
[9.3,1.2,87.9]
[1.0,1.0]
[0.0,0.0,1.0]
```

The first number, `3` is the number of vectors as we can see in the image, but that number isn't static, the input can be `5` or `7`, etc instead of `3`.

So far, I've started doing the following, (for only 1 vector case) but the code has some memory errors I think:

```
int main(){
    int n; //number of string, comes in the input
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    read = getline(&line,&len,stdin); //here the program assigns memory for the 1st string
    int numsvector = NumsVector(line, read);//calculate the amount of numbers in the strng
    float nfloat[numsvector];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numsvector; ++i)
    {
        if(numsvector == 1){
            sscanf(line, "[%f]", &nfloat[i]);
        }
        else if(numsvector == 2){
            if(i == 0) {
                sscanf(line, "[%f,", &nfloat[i]);
                printf("%f ", nfloat[i]);
            }
            else if(i == (numsvector-1)){
                sscanf((line+1), "%f]", &nfloat[i]);
                printf("%f\n", nfloat[i]);
            }
        }
    else {   //Here is where I think the problems are
        if(i == 0) {
            sscanf(line, "[%f,", &nfloat[i]);
            printf("%f\n", nfloat[i]);

        }
        else if(i == (numsvector-1)) {
            sscanf((line+1+(4*i)), "%f]", &nfloat[i]);
            printf("%f\n", nfloat[i]);
        }
        else {
            sscanf((line+1+(4*i)), "%f,", &nfloat[i]);
            printf("%f\n", nfloat[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the problems come with the `sscanf` instructions I think, in the case of a string with two floats or one, the code works fine but in the case of 3 or more floats, the code doesn't work well and I can't understand why...

Here I attach the function too, but It seems to be correct... the focus of the problem remains on the main.

```
int NumsVector(char *linea, ssize_t size){
        int numsvector = 1; //minimum value = 1
        int n;
        for(n = 2; n<= size; n++){
            if (linea[n] != '[' && linea[n] != ']'){
                if(linea[n] == 44){
                    numsvector = numsvector + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return numsvector;
}
```

Please could someone help me understand where is the problem?

Comment: Can't see anything that justifies the calculation `(line+1+(4*i))`. It assumes that your floats are three characters long, but that isn't true even in the data you've provided. I think the approach is wrong, some kind of tokenization is needed, maybe even using strtok.

Comment: Yes, I think the same thing but I can only use the statement sscanf :(

Comment: I can't see anything related to [tag:c++] in your code. Remove the tag or pick one of them.

Comment: What about the function getline, can you share the code for that? If nothing else it would let someone run the program and see if they have the same problems as you have.

Comment: Why do you use `linea[n] == 44` instead of `linea[n] == ','`?

Comment: @john No code for getline, is a standard feature included in the headers that I used:


        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>

Comment: @chux, because line[n] == 44 it's the same but in decimal value...

Comment: @john about the calculation (line+1+(4*i))...that's the problem, I do not see how it should calculate correctly

Comment: @Gerard Well you can't calculate it, the only way is to search for commas and then read the numbers between the commas (user2609288 is saying something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - if you replace your current for loop with this, your nfloat array should end up with the right numbers in it.

```
/* Replaces the end ] with a , */
line[strlen(line) - 1] = ',';

/* creates a new pointer, pointing after the first [ in the original string */
char *p = line + 1;
do
{
    /* grabs up to the next comma as a float */
    sscanf(p, "%f,", &nfloat[i]);
    /* prints the float it's just grabbed to 2 dp */
    printf("%.2f\n",nfloat[i]);
    /* moves pointer forward to next comma */
    while (*(p++) != ',');
}
while (++i < numsvector); /* stops when you've got the expected number */
```

Comment: Awesome! It works :D! But it prints some garbage, for example in the input we can see: [9.3,1.2,87.9], but doing some printf we can see:


[9.300000,1.200000,87.900002]

Comment: @Gerard Usually, you thank someone in stackoverflow by voting up / accepting their answer

Comment: I think you're seeing a floating point precision error. Not much you can do, except only use 2 d.p. when you print because the data appears to be that way anyway. I've updated my answer above to include the 2 d.p. printf statement.